# My simple RSA encryptor/decrypted wont work with values over 3?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

So I have a problem, I just learned this morning how to make an RSA encryptor/decrypted with the following variables:

```
p = 5, 
q = 11, 
n = 55, 
PHI = 40, 
e = 11, 
d = 11
```

And when I enter it into this (BTW this is JAVA):

```
public void draw() {

    int p = 5, q = 11, n = 55, PHI = 40, e = 11, d = 11;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    message = in.nextInt();

    println(' ');
    ecripted_message = Math.pow(message, e);// m^3
    ecripted_message %= n;

    println("This is the ecripted message " + ecripted_message);

    println(' ');
    message = Math.pow(ecripted_message, d);
    message %= n;

    println(' ');
    println("This is the origanal message " + message);
}
```

but when I enter anything three and above I get this in my console:

```
1

This is the ecripted message 1.0

This is the origanal message 1.0

2

This is the ecripted message 13.0

This is the origanal message 2.0

3

This is the ecripted message 47.0

This is the origanal message 24.0
```

Keep i mind that I am a very un-expiranced coder and I am relatively new.

Comment: 47^11 (as 13^11 but you've been lucky in that case with modular arithmetic) is too huge to be store in an `int`, you are experiencing integer overflow. You need to use some other number computation system, look at BigInteger class.

Comment: As Jean-Babtiste notes, you need something that handles larger numbers. 47^11 is 2,472,159,215,084,012,303, and mod 55 gives 3, not 24. Print out your computed value for 47^11 and you will likely find it has been truncated due to overflow.

Comment: Yes, you need modulo exponentiation. Modulo exponentiation is not the same as exponentiation and then taking the modulus *if* the numbers have a maximum value. You'd run into either the issue that 1) you have number overflows (which unfortunately never throw an exception in Java for the basic types) and 2) you run into memory and performance problems. Conceptually: the internal multiplications also need to be performed modulo n.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Though you said I need something that can handle a bigger number, is eclipse on a Mac Book Pro from early 2014 with 3.0 ghz and 8 gigs of memory not enough?